# Writing S4 method based on base R concatenation function c(). Use of ellipsis, dots ,

Tags: r, methods, concatenation, ellipsis, r-s4

I am trying to write a method for concatenation of two S4 classes that I have defined:

```
setClass("My_item",
         representation(contents = "vector"))

setClass("My_group",
         representation(members = "list"))
```

The `members` of every instance of the `My_group` class are all members of the `My_item` class but I have not included here the validation code that enforces that requirement.

I wish to write a concatenation method for the `My_group` class based on `c()` from base R. Its inputs will be any number (including zero) of elements which might be a mixture of members of either `My_item` class or the `My_group` class. The method should return a single member of the `My_group` class consisting of all the `My_item` members in the inputs, just as `c(c(1, 2), 3)` returns `c(1, 2, 3)`.

I understand that the definition of my method must follow exactly the definition of `c()` and so must take the following form:

```
setMethod(
  f = "c",
  signature = "My_group",
  definition = function(x, ..., recursive = FALSE) {
    [code to be written]
}
)
```

My question is about the function that does the work.

I can write a straight R function that does what I want:

```
myf<- function(...){
  elements <- list(...) 
  if (length(elements) != 0) { 
    items <- unlist(lapply(
      elements,
      FUN = function(object) {
        if (is(object, "My_group")) {
          return(getMy_group(object))
        } else {
          return(object)
        }
      }
    ))
    object <- new("My_group",
                  members = items )
  } else {
    object <-  new("My_group")
  }
}
```

(`getMy_group` is a simple method that unpacks a member of the `My_group` class into a list of its members.)

If I define `a1, a2, a3` as members of the `My_item` class, and `g1` as a `My_group` with members `a1` and `a2`,

```
a1 <- new("My_item", contents = c(1, 2, 3))
a2 <- new("My_item", contents = c( "x", "y", "z"))
a3 <- new("My_item", contents = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))

g1 <- new("My_group", members = list(a1, a2))
```

then `myf(g1, a3)` returns a `My_group` with 3 members, as required.

```
R>str(myf(g1, a3))
Formal class 'My_group' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 slot
  ..@ members:List of 3
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'My_item' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. ..@ contents: num [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'My_item' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. ..@ contents: chr [1:3] "x" "y" "z"
  .. ..$ :Formal class 'My_item' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. ..@ contents: num [1:3] 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

But if I define my method using the same code as in the function `myf`, as follows:

```
setMethod(
  f = "c",
  signature = "My_group",
  definition = function(x, ..., recursive = FALSE) {
    elements <- list(...) 
    if (length(elements) != 0) { 
      items <- unlist(lapply(
        elements,
        FUN = function(object) {
          if (is(object, "My_group")) {
            return(getMy_group(object))
          } else {
            return(object)
          }
        }
      )) 
      object <- new("My_group",
                    members = items)
    } else {
      object <- new("My_group")
    }

    return(object)
  }
)
```

I get the wrong answer:

```
 R>c(g1, a3)
An object of class "My_group"
Slot "members":
[[1]]
An object of class "My_item"
Slot "contents":
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

The method appears to have ignored `g1`.

I suspect I have misunderstood the role of the, to me, mysterious `x` that appears in the definition of `c()`, but I can't get any further than that in my diagnosis.

Edit: following JDL's helpful and reasoned suggestion that I use `setClassUnion` I wrote the following with a simple method that is supposed merely to return the arguments supplied to `c()`.:

```
    setClassUnion("mySortOfThing",c("My_item","My_group"))
    setMethod(
     f = "c",
     signature = "mySortOfThing",
     definition = function(x, ..., recursive = FALSE) {
      elements <- list(...)
      return(elements)
     }
    )
```

But I find

```
    g3 <- c(g1, a3) 
    R>str(g3)
    List of 1
     $ :Formal class 'My_item' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 1 slot
      .. ..@ contents: num [1:3] 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

I am obviously still getting something wrong.

Second edit: alan o'callaghan's suggestion solved the problem. For the record my method is now:

```
setMethod(
  f = "c",
  signature = "My_union",
  definition = function(x, ..., recursive = FALSE) {
    elements <- list(x, ...)
    if (length(elements) != 0) { 
      items <- unlist(lapply(
        elements,
        FUN = function(object) {
          if (is(object, "My_group")) {
            return(getMy_group(object))
          } else {
            return(object)
          }
        }
      ))

      object <- new("My_group",
                    members = items)
    } else {
      object <- new("My_group")
    }

    return(object)
  }
)
```

That yields:

```
R>c(g1, a3)
An object of class "My_group"
Slot "members":
[[1]]
An object of class "My_item"
Slot "contents":
[1] 1 2 3


[[2]]
An object of class "My_item"
Slot "contents":
[1] "x" "y" "z"


[[3]]
An object of class "My_item"
Slot "contents":
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3
```

which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This looks like the correct method is being called, but something is amiss in the body of the code. Could you add a `print` statement to the start of the `mySortOfThing` method and see whether it prints out?

Comment: Ah, you have a separate problem. I see it now, I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: I think if you change `list(...)` to `list(x, ...)` for `lapply`, your method should work? I'd post an answer but without your `getMy_group` method I can't demo my code. Side note: mixing CamelCase with snake_case to make Camel_snakes upsets me greatly :)

Comment: @alanocallaghan That worked! If you could turn your comment into an Answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JDL noted, `x` is used for method dispatch. Your function was ignoring it and only using `...`. This should work (untested)

```r
setMethod(
  f = "c",
  signature = "My_group",
  definition = function(x, ..., recursive = FALSE) {
    elements <- list(x, ...) 
    if (length(elements) != 0) { 
      items <- unlist(lapply(
        elements,
        FUN = function(object) {
          if (is(object, "My_group")) {
            return(getMy_group(object))
          } else {
            return(object)
          }
        }
      )) 
      object <- new("My_group",
                    members = items)
    } else {
      object <- new("My_group")
    }

    return(object)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to use `...` to select methods if the arguments that make `...` don't all have the same class. So your approach works if you feed `c` a bunch of `my_item` objects or a bunch of `my_group` objects, but not if you feed it a mixture.

From the help page for `dotsMethods`:

"Methods defined for such functions will be selected and called when all the arguments matching “...” are from the specified class or from some subclass of that class.

[...]

When you have a computation that is suitable for more than one existing class, a convenient approach may be to define a union of these classes by a call to setClassUnion."

So the recommended approach would be to make a class union:

```
setClassUnion("mySortOfThing",c("my_item","my_group"))
```

and then write a method for `c` that uses `mySortOfThing` as its signature for `...`,

Edit:

The given code has a separate problem ,in that `c` matches its arguments `positionally`. In the default definition of `c`, there is only the `...` argument. The question defines a method with arguments `x,...,recursive` which can mean that the first argument doesn't go where you expect it to and might be ignored. If you need a separate argument `x` then you will have to put it *after* the `...`.

Comment: I don't need a separate x argument at all,but I have to have it because it is in the definition of the generic c().: R>getGeneric("c")
standardGeneric for "c" defined from package "base"

function (x, ...) 
standardGeneric("c", .Primitive("c"))
<bytecode: 0x10349e5c8>
<environment: 0x10349a3d0>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x
Use  showMethods("c")  for currently available ones.

Comment: That is strange — the definition of `c` itself (not the generic) just has `...` as the only argument. I confess at this point I'm not sure what maps to what in terms of the arguments to `c`, the generic, and the final method. What happens when you try `c(x=g1,a3)` as opposed to `c(g1,a3)`?

Comment: As I said in my original question, the role of the x in the definition of the generic c() is mysterious to me. It has  to be there in any method based on c() but its function is unexplained. alan ocallaghan's solution works but I still don't know why.